# Getting error in Hydra

Tags: penetration-test, http, hydra

I'm trying to test someones website for them and I'm using hydra in cygwin on Windows. When I enter:

```
hydra -L myusers.txt -P mypass.txt website.net  http-get-form \
  "/wp-login.php:user_login=^USER^&user_pass=^PASS^"
```

(also tried with IP address)

I get the error:

```
Wrong syntax, requires three arguements seperated by a colon which
may not be null: /wp-login.php
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a `http-post-form`, instead of a `http-get-form`? Also you will probably have to enable SSL/TLS. Your syntax looks fine though, you just need to append the `:failure message` to the end of what you've got.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the text that's returned upon an incorrect response.

From `hydra -U http-get-form`:

```
Syntax:   <url>:<form parameters>:<condition string>[:<optional>[:<optional>]
```

"Condition string" needs to be populated. This is something the site returns when the password is wrong and is site specific. e.g. "`Incorrect password`".